# How to make Python input() not clear output in threaded program

Tags: python, multithreading, input, output

I have 2 threads, one is input and the second is output from sockets. I'm making some sort of console for server of my game. I tried:

```py
def IOelvex():
    while(True):
        try:
            bap = server.recvfrom(bufferSize)
            message = bap[0]
            print(message)

def InputConsole():
    while (true):
        oprint('input> ', end='')
        a = input()
IOThread = threading.Thread(target=IOelvex)
ConsoleThread = threading.Thread(target=InputConsole)
```

but I receive this:

> input> sadasd[ERROR][2019-11-03 12:20:51] Tried to get user, but user with that name doesn't exists. (V1ktor)
>   [ERROR][2019-11-03 12:20:52] Tried to get user, but user with that name doesn't exists. (V1ktor)
>   [ERROR][2019-11-03 12:20:52] Tried to get user, but user with that name doesn't exists. (V1ktor)
>   [ERROR][2019-11-03 12:20:52] Tried to get user, but user with that name doesn't exists. (V1ktor)

and when I type something in input, all output logs after `>` just disappears.

Comment: Can you post the full code so we can reproduce? `server` is not defined anywhere, and we don't know which libraries are being used. Other than that, you may want to keep the interactive part `input()` inside the main thread rather than creating an additional thread for it.

Comment: That is not needed, I showed the fact of output, It's can be any output.